# Cannot move dock icons in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, dock, applications

When I drag an existing icon from one place to another in Mountain Lion I cannot click to release it. It just remains 'stuck' to the mouse pointer.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes with everything running on your Mac it can get clustered and not be as responsive, Try and go to Applications->Utilities->Activity Monitor and Find Dock PID 167. Then click it and Quit process, This will close the dock and reopen it. And that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted your machine? Sometimes when I get working on lots of tasks on my Mac, it takes awhile to get any response from the dock. I save and close out of all my apps and restart the machine.

Comment: yes of course. several times before I posted.